# Clip grouped or stacked images in inkscape

Tags: image, inkscape

I have bunch of images of cells from different channels, imageA_c1.tif, imageA_c2.tif and imageA_c3.tif

I wish to clip a bounding box through all the images at the exact same location.

So I imported the 3 images.

Then I align them and group them.

I then set a rectangle at a region of interest on top of these grouped images and then do Path->clip

Clipping is fine.

However, when I ungroup the objects, the clipping is lost and the images revert to their full original size.

Is there a way to retain the crop images using a bounding box through a stack of images and retain them after ungrouping?

Thanks
Lee